# commands work in home directory, but not anywhere else

Tags: macos, flutter, zsh, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to set up a dev environment on my Mac Mini running Bir Sur 11.2.3. I can add commands to the `.zshrc` file, but they only seem to work in my home directory. For example...

```
chris@chriss-mac-mini an_app % which flutter dart
flutter not found
dart not found

chris@chriss-mac-mini an_app % cd ~

chris@chriss-mac-mini ~ % which flutter dart
dev/flutter/bin/flutter
dev/flutter/bin/dart
```

My .zshrc file looks like this...

```
chris@chriss-mac-mini ~ % cat .zshrc
export PATH="$PATH:dev/flutter/bin"
```

Why am I unable to use the flutter command in other directories on this machine?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: change the line in your .zshrc to this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/dev/flutter/bin"
```

Long answer: the path you added to your `PATH` environment variable, `dev/flutter/bin`, doesn't start with "/" so it's a *relative* path, meaning it'll be resolved relative to wherever your current working directory happens to be. If you're in `/Users/cjmcqueen` (or whatever your home directory is), it'll resolve to `/Users/cjmcqueen/dev/flutter/bin`, which is presumably where the actual binaries are. But if you're in `/random/other/path`, it'll resolve to `/random/other/path/dev/flutter/bin`, which probably doesn't even exist (let alone contain binaries for the `flutter`, `dart`, etc commands).

To solve this, you need to add a full absolute path to the binaries, instead of a relative one. In some situations, `~` will expand to the path to your home directory (so `~/dev/flutter/bin` will work), but not in all situations. In this particular situation, `$HOME` is better because the shell will expand it to the absolute path to your home directory *before* storing it in the `PATH` variable, so you don't have to depend on something else resolving it later.

Comment: `zsh` does apply filename expansion when the `~` immediately follows a `:`, to accommodate its usage for `PATH`, etc. (Beats me where exactly this is documented, though.)

Comment: This fixed my issue on my M1, worked in Home but not anywhere else, but then android studio would still build with flutter but I couldn't run commands, much better thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`export PATH="$PATH:dev/flutter/bin"` is referencing a relative path.

`dev/flutter/bin` should be something like `/Users/<user>/dev/flutter/bin`.

In the terminal, go to the directory for your flutter bin folder and type `pwd`. This is the full path it should reference.